# Proof of inverse function derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I’m studying the inverse function derivative theorem and I found the proof given by my book a bit sloppy, so I am trying to fill the gaps.

> Let $f$ a continous strictly monotone function in $[a,b]$ differentiable in $x$ then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable in $f(x)=y$. And moreover: $$(f^{-1})’(y)=\frac{1}{f’(x)}$$

**Proof**

$$(f^{-1})’(y)=\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(y+k)-f^{-1}(y)}{k} = $$
$$=\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(y+k)-f^{-1}(y)}{(y+k)-y} =$$
$$= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(f(x+h(k)))-f^{-1}(f(x))}{f(x+h(k))-f(x)}$$
Where clearly $ h$ depends on $k$ so I wrote $h(k)$ :

$$= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{h(k)}{f(x+h(k))-f(x)}$$

Now ***my book*** suggests this:

$$= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{h(k)}{f(x+h(k))-f(x)}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h}{f(x+h)-f(x)} $$

I agree that as $k \to 0$ , $h \to 0$ because of the continuity of $f$, but I think we should justify why we can make that substitution (because in general we can’t always apply substitutions). I thought that maybe we could justify the substitution this way:

$$ \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{h(k)}{f(x+h(k))-f(x)}= \lim_{k\to 0} g(h(k))$$

Where $g(t)=\frac{t}{f(x+t)-f(x)}$. Now notice that $g$ is continous since because $t$ is continous and since $f$ is continous also $f(x+t)-f(x)$ is continous and it’s always non-zero because $f$ is strictly monotone. This justify the substitution. Is this formalization correct, incorrect or useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can justify the substitution in the way you suggest. The following assumptions guarantee that the substitution is valid: $g$ is continuous at $t=0$ and $\lim_{k\to 0}h(k)=0$. The latter follows from the way $h$ is defined. And $g$ can be extended to a continuous function by defining $g(0)=1/f'(x)$.

Another set of assumptions that suffices is $\lim_{k\to 0}h(k)=0$ and $h(k)\ne 0$ in some neighborhood of $k=0$ (without any assumption about continuity of $g$ at $t=0$). This is also true here but it requires to use the fact that if $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous and strictly increasing. Presumably, $h$ is defined as $h(k)=f^{-1}(y+k)-x$. Then, $h(k)=0\Rightarrow f^{-1}(y+k)=x=f^{-1}(y)\Rightarrow k=0$ since $f^{-1}$ is injective.

Comment: Oops I didn't notice the discontinuity in 0.  Are we allowed to "modify" g?

Comment: @Eureka You're the one defining $g$, so yes. You can define your way for $t\ne 0$ and as $1/f'(x)$ for $t=0$. This way, it's continuous at $t=0$. I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: the second option convinced me ,thank you :). I would love this formalism in my book.